# Unable to access SMB on Domain-Joined machines

Tags: samba

Hoping someone may be able to assist, or give any tips to try and resolve this issue.

I've recently spun up a new Ubuntu server and configured samba to allow windows clients easy access. I CAN successfully access this share on multiple Windows machines on the network which are not domain-joined. However, I cannot access it via any Windows machines on the same network which ARE on a domain.

To make things more confusing, our old Ubuntu server can be accessed fine without any issues from the domain-joined machines.

Details:

- Neither the old or new Ubuntu server are part of the domain
- The old ubuntu server can be accessed fine from any machine
- The new ubuntu server cannot be accessed from domain-joined machines
- All firewalls have been disabled, same issue occurs.
- I CAN successfully ping, and access other resources (i.e. web-based apps) on this new ubuntu server, the issue is only SMB.

Old Ubuntu Server stats:

- Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Running SMBD 4.13.17

New Ubuntu Server stats:

- Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Running SMBD 4.15.5

When trying to access the new SMB server from a Windows machine on the domain, the credentials box does not appear, and instead an error: Windows can't find \10.100.0.60 Check the spelling and try again.

This can be access from the same network on a non-domain PC without issue.

Answer (score 2):

Literally just resolved this after hours of fault-finding!

On the domain-joined machines, I opened Credential Manager, added a new Windows Credential with the login details of the Ubuntu server. I Had to add the username in the following format: IPAddress\Username

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this! I thought I was going mad trying to figure this out.